# Получить информацию о пользователях Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Есть ли способы получить инфо о пользователях?

Метод `{user-id}` возвращает только имя/фамилию пользователя.

Мне требуется:

- Получить список пользователей которые лайкнули или расшарили пост
- Получить информацию по каждому пользователю (id, город, страна, пол, возраст и т.д.)

Comment: вы [документацию](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) читали? по пользователю можно кучу информации получить; для [лайков](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/likes) получаете user_id и работаете с ними. Только большая часть информации о пользователе закрыта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Получение записи в Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/likes), соответственно ID объекта — ID поста.
- Далее делаете по полученным ID пользователей [отдельные запросы](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user).
  Возможности делать подобие объединения запросов для оптимизации нет, может помочь только вот эта информация относительно множественных запросов к [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests).

Comment: Объединять запросы можно через `?ids=...`, только не уверен, что только по лайку можно получить какую-либо полезную информацию. Если есть логин через FB, то для тех, кто залогинился, можно получить некоторую информацию, а для остальных она сильно урезана

Comment: Можно указать большой `limit` для первого запроса, получить все `id` пользователей, а потом уже использовать `ids` при запросы информации о пользователях — так можно будет обойтись 2 запросами.

Comment: без access_token'а получить можно только самый минимум информации. Чтобы получить подробную информацию о пользователе необходимо чтобы пользователь каким-либо образом разрешил это, например, через выдачу разрешений при логине на сайте.